# What is not Cellular Automata?

Tags: cellular-automata

Generalized a specific question I had which is:

Would it still be called Cellular Automata if the state of the cell depended on the state of all the other cells in the grid?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes. Expand the grid size to n-dimensional neighborhood:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cellular_Automata/Neighborhood

Comment: There is also toroidal cellular automata: http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/CellularAutomatonLikeNeuralNetworkInAToroidalVectorField/ this results in grid wrapping which makes all states dependent on others as state wraps.

Comment: What n-dimensional CA has to do with the proposed definition of a transition function?